# What is the output of the loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a loop in PYTHON 3.X.

```
for i in range(2, 2):
   print(i)
```

The result that I got after running this program was a blank console. 
What type of output we get from this loop.

Comment: What do you expect to output?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting blank output is because what the `range()` function does.

The first argument in the `range()` function tells the function which number to iterate to.

So, if this was your code:

```py
for i in range(2):
    print(i)
```

Then your output would be:

```
0
1
```

It starts from 0 and prints two numbers, because of the two.

However, the second parameter **in your code** tells it what to count by. For example, you added a 2 for the second parameter. This tells the program to skip count by 2, and since you have only 2 output in the first place, the program doesn't print anything

Read up on [range in python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The two parameter version of range is `range(start, stop)` not `range(start, step)`

Comment: @SpoonMeiser I was simply speaking about the OP's code, not in general.

Comment: No, I mean that your paragraph about the second parameter to range is just incorrect; the answer would be improved by fixing that.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser OK I will fix it. Thanks for pointing out the error!

Comment: I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The range of numbers returned are integers from start to stop. ( the first param being start, and second being stop when 2 are given)

It includes the start int, but not the stop int.

hence, `range(2,2)` contains no numbers in between.

`range(2,4)` returns `2,3` but not `4`.

Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).